# Edit datagridview in runtime and update database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I searched some posts but still cant get it work.

I have a window application written in C#, Here I bind the datagridview to my database:

```
public static DataSet GetDataSet(string sql)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;

        }
    }
```

and I bind the datagridview in another class:

```
string sql = "select Amount, Price, Description from myTable";
ds = DbHelper.GetDataSet(sql);
dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

I created a button for user to update the database after they edit the datagridview:

```
string sql = "select Amount, Price, Description from myTable";
DbHelper.UpdateDataSet(sql, ds);
MessageBox.Show("done");

public static void UpdateDataSet(string sql, DataSet ds)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn);
            da.Update(ds);
        }
    }
```

Here is the error, occurs at the line `da.Update(ds);`:

Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

Thanks for help.

**EDIT**
I can get it work with this:

```
SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.UpdateCommand = commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
```

But only when I show the key in the datagridview as well, otherwise:

Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

How to overcome this if I dont want to show the key in datagridview?

Comment: How do you expect to update the database with `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlCommandBuilder needs the Primary Key to update the field. You can still load the key to the DataGridView, but **hide** the column.